# Add elements inside a chat window

Tags: ios, chat

I am developing an application which is built heavy around chat between a user and a call centre.  I recently saw an article about the Native Travel App and saw a screenshot which perk'd my interest:

[image]

My question is how have they developed scrolling elements within a chat window? Can anyone point me in the direction of some sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am making chat functionality as we speak. I am achieving it by using a tableView that is scrolled to the bottom. Each time you receive a new message, you append it to the array that your table uses as the datasource and then scroll the table down to the bottom

[image]

For the sideways scrolling aspect of this chat, i would create another prototyped cell that contains a scrollview that can be populated with content that the user can scroll through horizontally.